# (my)sql get results from optional table

Tags: mysql, sql, option-type, relation

I have simple pricing model:

---

```
**table reseller**

| **id** | **reseller** |

| 1     |    john |

| 2     |    mary |

| 3     |    peter |
```

---

```
**table products**

| **id** | **product** | **advisory_price** |

| 1     |     apple    |    1.99 |

| 2    |      pear    |     2.99 |

| 3     |     plumb    |    3.99 |
```

---

```
**table custom_price**

| **id** | **product_id** | **reseller_id** | **retail_price**

| 1     |     1        |        1         |        2.50 |

| 2     |     1        |        3         |        2.80 |

| 3     |     3        |        1         |        4.50 |
```

---

the idea is that custom price is optional for resellers so if they didnt specify it and thus no corresponding row exist in custom_price table the default 'advisory_price' is shown

my initial thought was:

```
SELECT 
    products.advisory_price, 
    custom_price.retail_price, 
COALESCE(retail_price, advisory_price) AS sales_price 
FROM products
LEFT JOIN custom_price
ON 
    products.id = custom_price.product_id
WHERE 
    (
    custom_price.reseller_id IS NULL 
        OR 
    custom_price.reseller_id='2'
    )
```

but this of course results in rows not showing up if not specified for this reseller but it was for others.

then i came up with a union:

```
SELECT 
    products.advisory_price, 
    custom_price.retail_price AS sales_price, 
FROM products
INNER JOIN custom_price
ON 
    products.id = custom_price.product_id
WHERE 
    custom_price.reseller_id='2'
UNION
SELECT 
    products.advisory_price AS retail_price, 
FROM products
WHERE products.id NOT IN 
    ( 
        SELECT product_id 
        FROM custom_price 
        WHERE reseller_id = '2' 
    )
```

basically this takes the retail_price AS sales_price from custom_price table if specified and concatenates all default prices that dont have a corresponding row in custom price table.

then i wanted to order on id but that gives an error, which is probably easily fixable but somehow i have the feeling this UNION is sort of overkill and it can be done in a much simpeler way than this really huge query.

am i right and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the Content of `WHERE` to the `ON`clause in your first query:

```
SELECT 
products.advisory_price, 
custom_price.retail_price, 
COALESCE(retail_price, advisory_price) AS sales_price 
FROM products
LEFT JOIN custom_price
ON 
products.id = custom_price.product_id AND custom_price.reseller_id='2'
```

Then it should work